# How to create a factory where two objects belong to the same parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factory:

```
factory :user do
    name 'Henk'
    email 'foo@bar.co'
    password 'foobar'
    password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
end

factory :photo do |ph|
    user
    ph.subtitle 'abc'
    ph.photo { fixture_file_upload( Rails.root.join( 'spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'test-file-one.png' ), 'image/png') }
end

factory :ad do |ad|
    user
    name 'Kip'
    reason 'Ik wil gewoon hele mooie nieuwe, om een beetje van te eten.'
    price 69.15
end
```

Both Photo and Ad belong to a User, however a Photo also belongs to an Ad. This is a problem, because whenever I test the relation between Photo and Add the user validation complains, correctly, that a user with that email is already in use. How do I tell rspec to use that same user again, and not try to create another user with the same factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to ensure the same parent is used is to pass the parent into the factory creation during the test. For example:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
@photo = FactoryGirl.create(:photo, user: @user)
@ad = FactoryGirl.create(:ad, user: @user)
```

This will ensure that both `photo` and `ad` use same `user` parent object so you will avoid the validation issues you have been having.

Comment: It took me a while to test this, but your solution works, thanks. In your opinion, is this a good db structure? My colleague suggested that photo should belong to ad which should belong to user, and that no direct relation between photo and user should exist, what do you think? Thanks for your reply^^

Comment: I usually try and think how the objects relate in terms of a particular solution. In this case does a user take or upload a photo, then perhaps it should belong to a user. Can a photo exist without an Ad, again it should belong to user or stand alone. Usually it is better to think about how the API or web pages themselves might work, and how users would interact with them, often this will make the relationships clearer.

Comment: Hah, that's what I said in the first place! Totally going to burn my colleague now! Thanks!